# Server Core 2012 domain controller & NAT in VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox

Scenario is a developer build out in VirtualBox.  I am looking to combine the DC with NAT (2 NICs, one internal and one NAT) running server core 2012.  A key goal is to hide the (internal) DEV domain from the outside world while still allowing any DEV VMs on the internal domain access to e.g. Windows Update.

Is this as simple as adding the NICs to the 2012 VM, installing the OS and then following one of the [tutorials](http://mssecbyben.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/howto-install-a-new-domain-on-server-2012-core/) for creating a domain controller?  Are there any steps I should take to prevent other physical hosts from seeing the DEV domain?

Thanks in advance for any insights, suggestions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prevent the external adapter from dynamically registering itself in DNS before you dcpromo, otherwise you're going to run into connectivity issues with clients inside of the private network.

[This Windows 2000 Server article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272294) is still relevant in this case.

Comment: Thank you!  I found a PS script to do this (since it's server core):
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/et-EE/ITCG/thread/616145bc-9667-4c38-a2a2-65975d686e5c

Will mark as answered once it's working.  Thanks again.

Comment: While the script above runs without error it does not seem to actually set the adapter's FullDNSRegistration status to false as seems to be desired if I understand the post.

Comment: After re-reading the original article you posted (thank you) I'm wondering if it wouldn't be simpler to set up the DC with a single, internal NIC and then add the second NIC after promotion.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It will still auto-register that second NIC eventually. Multi-homed domain controllers are messy. Really consider just not doing it at all.

Comment: Point taken.  Maybe I asked the wrong question initially.  What is the best way to achieve the primary goal of running a domain on an internal network and still providing external access for the DEV VMs on the network?  And thanks again for the help / guidance so far.